# Bootstrap scrollspy not working on iPad

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap scrollspy working fine for the most part on this site: http://www.profitplaybook.com/temp/

However, when I view the page on an iPad, click, say, the "Contact" link and then scroll up, the Scrollspy effect is broken and highlights the wrong menu items. Any ideas on how this could be fixed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have been facing the same issue. Bootstrap scrollspy does not seem to like iPad.