# Apply media query when page scrolled without JS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I want to apply media query only when page scrolled `xxxx pixels down` Is there any way I can do that with media query without JS?

**UPDATED**
The reason I am asking because none of JS plugins based on offset position are working on iPad, iPhone and Safari, they are not calculating offset properly [Fixed position delayed on IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772451/affix-failing-on-ipad) and [Bootstrap scrollspy not working on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703513/bootstrap-scrollspy-not-working-on-ipad)

So I thought may be I can do that with media query if it is possible.

Comment: what is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: if you want to fire events on scroll positions there are plugins which you can use  [Prinzhorn Skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn), [waypoint](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)

Comment: plugins not working on iPad and i guess on any iOS based browser.

Comment: i have been using them and they work

Comment: they are `kind of work`

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do that with a media query, media queries are used to test screen sizes for responsive web design.

You're going to have to use javascript to check scroll position then apply the media query accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you could use twitter bootstrap scrollspy method: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with Media Queries, but you are able to do this with JavaScript. If you're having issues with ScollSpy maybe take a look at [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/). This works on mobile and is an incredible library to have in your toolbelt. This will let you react to the user's scrolled position.